# JSON date in javascript not works

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC web site, in some views I show a datetime from JSON value, frist I show month in one input/text control and the year in other control. The website is used by many cities and works fine, but in one city when I convert JSON date value to Javascript date value, date value has one month less, for example if JSON date is 2016-04-01 12:00:00 Javascript date value is 2016-03-01, I think is a configuration of the PC is this city but what configuration?

This is the code:

```
var Ffab = new Date(parseInt(item.Ffab_ettc.replace(/\/Date\((.*?)\)\//gi, "$1")));
                $("#txtFfabTCM").val(Ffab.getMonth() + 1);
                $("#txtFfabTCY").val(Ffab.getFullYear());
```

item.Ffab_ettc is the JSON Datetime value.

Comment: "JSON Datetime" is not something I know. Assuming `item.Ffab_ettc` contains `"Date(2016-04-01 12:00:00)"`, the replace will make that `"2016-04-01 12:00:00"`, which you then try to parse as an int?!

Comment: @Samurai8 item.FFab_ettc has /Date(1438405200000)/